# If one cell equals another, the copy and paste a different cell

Tags: vba, excel

Ok.
I have the following code that keeps crashing Excel for me, but I can't figure out why. I have basically the same exact code that I have used multiple times with no problem.

Basically, I have last names and first names in two different workbooks, and if they equal each other, I want to copy the date of birth from the one workbook to other workbook.

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim iRow As Integer, cRow As Integer

iRow = 4

Dim wbC As Workbook, wbA As Workbook, wsC As Worksheet, wsA As Worksheet

Set wbC = Workbooks("Coventry Enroll Census  113014")
Set wbA = Workbooks("Copy of Ameritas Enroll Census Template 1 1 15 (2).xls")
Set wsC = wbC.Sheets(1)
Set wsA = wbA.Sheets(2)

Do: cRow = 2 'Reset cRow
        'DOB
        If wsC.Cells(cRow, 2) = wsA.Cells(iRow, 2) And wsC.Cells(cRow, 1) = wsA.Cells(iRow, 3)Then
         wsC.Cells(cRow, 10).Select
         Selection.Copy
           Range(wsA.Cells(iRow, 6)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
         iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
        cRow = cRow + 1

        End If

        Loop Until wsC.Cells(cRow, 1) = "" And wsC.Cells(cRow + 1, 1) = "" And wsC.Cells(cRow + 2, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when it crashes? Do you get an error or does Excel just close? The `selection.copy` part could be problematic since that would take a chunk of memory

Comment: Excel just closes. I didn't think it would be too much memory because it is only one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created and endless loop as you reset `cRow` at the begin of each loop. So probably the `until` conditions never will be true because cRow is either 2 or 3. I can't really explain the crashing but I think it is related to that. Try setting `cRow = 2` before the `Do` of the loop.

Comment: I think I added that into this code without thinking about it, so my other ones didn't do that endless thing.

Comment: @TylerYoder: Sh.t happens ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the values directly instead of selecting them. I can't say for sure if this is going to solve your problem without having your workbooks and system, but give it a shot.

Also, Check out [this link about avoiding using Select statements in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

```
Do: cRow = 2 'Reset cRow
        'DOB
        If wsC.Cells(cRow, 2) = wsA.Cells(iRow, 2) And wsC.Cells(cRow, 1) = wsA.Cells(iRow, 3) Then
            wsA.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = wsC.Cells(cRow, 10).Value    'THIS SETS ONLY THE VALUE.
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
            cRow = cRow + 1
        End If

        Loop Until wsC.Cells(cRow, 1) = "" And wsC.Cells(cRow + 1, 1) = "" And wsC.Cells(cRow + 2, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

**SIDE NOTE:** 
Are you intending to include the file extention in wbA and not wbC?  From your code:

```
Set wbC = Workbooks("Coventry Enroll Census  113014")
Set wbA = Workbooks("Copy of Ameritas Enroll Census Template 1 1 15 (2).xls")
```

edit notes:  Added Side Note.

Comment: Thanks for that link about Select statements!  I'm sure it will come in handy for me down the road.